# Why the key representing radio buttons goes missing from the HTTP POST method's $_POST superglobal array when none of them are selected?

Tags: php, http, http-post, httprequest, superglobals

I've written following PHP code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>  

    <?php
      // define variables and set to empty values
      $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
        die;  
      }
    ?>

    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
      Name: <input type="text" name="name">
      <br><br>
      E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
      <br><br>
      Website: <input type="text" name="website">
      <br><br>
      Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
      <br><br>
      Gender:
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I submitted the form without entering data in any of the form firled or selecting any of the two radio buttons that are present on the HTML form I got following result :

```
Array
(
    [name] => 
    [email] => 
    [website] => 
    [comment] => 
    [submit] => Submit
)
```

In above result, I could see the names of all input form controls, even the key representing the text-area is also present within the `$_POST`array. The only expected thing that is missing from the above `$_POST` array output is the key representing the radio buttons **'gender**'

This is my doubt. Why it's going missing from the output of `$_POST` array?

When I fill in the form controls, select any of the radio buttons everything works fine, no issues with it.

Are there any other similar HTML form controls which behave like radio buttons are behaving in above code which I have written?

Please someone clear my doubt and explain me the reason behind this behavior.

Thank You.

Comment: this is normal behaviour

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes, I know there is not an issue and it's a normal behavior but my doubt is  why the blank values from other input fields and text-area field get submit to the server? Why this principal is not applicable to all other controls?

Comment: because your radios have value (but not selected) and the inputs need to be filled (and have no default preset value). Had you given your inputs default values, then that would have probably avoided the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you don't select a radio input, no data is sent to the server.
As shown in the MDN:

> Note: If no radio button is selected when the form is submitted, there
>   is no value submitted to the server to represent the unselected state
>   (e.g., value=unselected); the value is not submitted to the server at
>   all.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Comment: Correct, but also behaviour is totally up to browser (whichever is used).

Comment: If such is the case then why the blank values from other input fields and text-area field get submit to the server? Why this principal is not applicable to all other controls?

Comment: @DejanMarjanovic:How does this behavior relate to the browser? Please explain.

Comment: @user2839497 what he's trying to say is, sending the data for unchecked radio inputs is decided by browsers, some browsers may send an empty value, others may not.

Comment: @MehdiBounya: I don't think so. If such is the case then how the 'some browsers' you are talking about decide which radio button should get select and the corresponding radio button value should get pass to the server?

Comment: @user2839497 I didn't mean it sends a default value, I meant that it sends an empty value with the input's name, like this `[gender] =>`, so when the browser encounters a group of Radio Inputs (grouped by a name) and none of them is selected, it sends nothing, but others send `input_name => ''`